# Naive bayes with bag-of-words for text classification in German: reading in the corpus

Tags: python, nltk, naivebayes

I would like to implement a Naive Bayes classifier for German. I am using NLTK and basically copying the code from the NLTK cookbook. I have put together a little corpus. I have a folder with two subfolders called neg and pos (like the movie review corpus). I am using a bag of word model.

This is how I process the corpus:

```
def bag_of_words(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words])

def bag_of_words_not_in_set(words, badwords):
    return bag_of_words(set(words) - set(badwords))

def bag_of_words_without_stopwords(words):
    badwords = stopwords.words("german")
    return bag_of_words_not_in_set(words, badwords)

def label_feats_from_corpus(corp, feature_detector=bag_of_words_without_stopwords):
    label_feats = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for label in corp.categories():
        for fileid in corp.fileids(categories=[label]):
            feats = feature_detector(corp.words(fileids=[fileid]))
            label_feats[label].append(feats)
    return label_feats

def label_feats_from_corpus(corp, feature_detector=bag_of_words_without_stopwords):
    label_feats = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for label in corp.categories():
        for fileid in corp.fileids(categories=[label]):
            print (label + " >> " + fieldid)
            feats = feature_detector(corp.words(fileids=[fileid]))
            print(feats)
            label_feats[label].append(feats)
    return label_feats

reader = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader('D:/corpus/', r'.*\.txt', cat_pattern=r'(\w+)/*')
```

For

```
print (label + " >> " + fieldid)
print(feats)
```

I get

```
neg >> neg/fdfdg.txt
{'autorisierten': True, 'durchführen': True, 'Sicherheit': True, 'Fachwerkstatt': True, 'Arbeiten': True, 'in': True, 'Lassen': True, 'im': True, 'Interesse': True}
neg >> neg/fdffdf.txt
{'Arbeiten': True, 'Fachkenntnisse': True, 'gekennzeichnet': True, 'Verständnis': True, 'technisches': True, 'erfordern': True, 'Symbol': True}
neg >> neg/fgfdgdgdg.txt
{'Arbeiten': True, 'Spezialwerkzeuge': True, 'notwendig': True}
neg >> neg/fgff.txt
{'aussetzen': True, 'niemals': True, 'Flüssigkeiten': True, 'Regen': True, 'Salzwasser': True, 'Feuchtigkeit': True, 'Nässe': True, 'Batterien': True, ').': True}
```

which means that feature selection worked, right? (Irrespecitive of whether they already are the best features)

I am just interested at this point to correctly read in the corpus and get the bag-of-words feature selction right.

Thanks for any help and feedback!